# In Android ListView, how to change the row height dynamically according to the setting of font-size of android devices

Tags: android, listview

In Android ListView, I would like to change the height of each row dynamically according to the setting of font-size of android devices.

I am trying to implementing it in "onWindowFocusChanged" method in my Main Activity as follows.

However, I have no idea how to change the height of each row.

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(final boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View listItem = adapter.getView(i, null, listView);
            // the process of change height of each row.
        }

    }

}
```

Could you tell me how to implement above?

Comment: Are u using an custom list-adapter?

Comment: Yes I use custom list-adapter.

Comment: Are u given somewhere an fixed height?

Comment: In xml file, I set an fixed height.

Comment: Make the height wrap_content?

Comment: I use android:minHeight="200dp".

Comment: Change the height in your xml code. If you increase/decrease the height of the parent or root element, the height of the list item will change accordingly. set it to wrap content with some padding or margins so that your text do not touch the edges of the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your inf_row xml imean in your row xml file you have to set height as wrap content.

```
             <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:text=""
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"  />
```